# Subject verb agreement with collective noun

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

> A bag of oranges that is ripe.

> A bag of oranges that are ripe.

Should bag or oranges agree with the verb here?
I think *are* is the correct choice here because oranges are what's ripe in this case.
But if the sentence was something like

> A bag of oranges that is torn

It would be *is* because the bag is the subject that is torn.

Is this the right way to think about this?

Comment: A bag of oranges **that are ripe**. But it isn't a question because we actually would say: A bag of ripe oranges. And a torn bag of oranges. Otherwise, to be clear you have to say: A bag of oranges, which is torn.

Comment: Yes, you are thinking in the right way.

Comment: *A bag of oranges that **is** ripe* is syntactically valid - it just has a different meaning. Specifically, that the (singular) ***bag*** containing the oranges is "ripe" (the bag has been washed so many times that the fibres have become weakened, so the fabric tears easily).

Comment: A ripe bag, I don't think so. That would be stinky, if anything.

Answer (score 0):

> A bag of oranges that are ripe.

> A bag of oranges that is torn.

Yes, your interpretations are fine.

Example 2, however, seems clumsy and could be re-constructed as Lambie has commented.

In example 1, the *that-clause* is a restrictive relative clause modifying *oranges*; the copula agrees with *oranges*, which is plural.

Comment: I would not accept "A bag of oranges that is torn", in an essay. Because a torn bag of oranges is available and better.

Answer (score 0):

1: (A bag)(sing) of oranges that is ripe (
Relative pronoun 'that' indicates 'a bag')

{I don't know whether the oranges are ripe,
but at least, the bag is ripe.}

2: A bag of oranges(pl) that are ripe (
'that' indicates 'oranges')

{I am interested in the contents of the bag.
They are all ripe.}

Comment: a ripe bag is pretty meaningless. ripe can mean stinky but the likelihood of that meaning here is next to zero.

Comment: A bag is ripe: kind of plump ?
It's difficult to imagine.(maybe grammatically correct, but unimaginable in the real life)

Comment: You said: "At least the bag is ripe". Ripe is not plump. Ripe means stinky: that smells bad.:)

Comment: It's difficult to choose proper word. ToT

Answer (score 0):

To avoid confusion, we can use adjectives before 'bag' and 'oranges'
We can say, *a torn bag*, *ripe oranges*, and *a torn bag of ripe oranges*.

'I have a red cow.' We don't need to say 'I have a cow that/which is red'.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have this right.

Your second sentence is maybe slightly strange, but perhaps only because of the specific example. If you said "A bag of mail that is torn" it sounds fine.

There are other cases where you could really go either way, like "A group of students that is/are noisy". The difference (I think) is that in those cases, the "group" is not a physical concept that the adjective either does or doesn't apply to.